# cygwin permission denied

Tags: cygwin

I have been trying to update the **Cygwin Program** so it can locate my files, however when i ran this command  ***'updatedb'***, I just got alot of - permission denied  responses from the program such as :

```
/usr/bin/find: `/cygdrive/d/Windows/ServiceProfiles/NetworkService': Permission denied
```

How can I solve this so I can locate my files using the **CYGWIN program.**

Ps- i am using a windows7 pc.

Thanks

Jis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as a solution... > cd / > mkdir c > mount c: /c > mkdir d > mount d: /d > ...etc –

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you installed cygwin as an administrator, but the current user does not have administrator rights?  If so, try running cygwin as admin and do `updatebd` that way.

Comment: How about the suggestions on [this site](http://bookweevil.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/getting-updatedb-on-cygwin-to-prune-paths-with-spaces/)?  The suggestion is to ignore those paths (using the `prune` option) as they can have system files that are currently in-use